# Cannot export local git repository using git bundle

Tags: git, version-control

I've been trying to export my local git repository using git bundle command. But it appears that not everything is exported. How do I properly export my local git repository? I've read that I shouldn't unbundle the bundle but I should clone it instead.

```
PS C:\dev\repo\local-repo> git status
On branch dev
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/dev'.
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   application/config/config.php
        modified:   application/controllers/Account.php
        modified:   application/controllers/Hook.php
        modified:   application/controllers/Test.php
        modified:   application/models/User.php
        modified:   application/views/backend/account/main.php
        modified:   application/views/backend/account/nav.php
        modified:   application/views/backend/referrals_table.php

Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        application/models/Permission.php
        application/models/Referral.php
        application/models/Resellercredit.php
        application/models/Resellerpackage.php
        application/models/Usergroup.php
        application/views/backend/account/reseller_center.php

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

PS C:\dev\repo\local-repo> git branch
* dev
master

PS C:\dev\repo\local-repo> git stash list
stash@{0}: On dev: linux migration stash

PS C:\dev\repo\local-repo> git bundle create ..\migrate.git --all
Counting objects: 4249, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1546/1546), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4249/4249), 10.17 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 4249 (delta 2709), reused 4186 (delta 2680)



PS C:\dev\repo> git clone migrate.git remote-repo
Cloning into 'remote-repo'...
Receiving objects: 100% (4249/4249), 10.17 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2709/2709), done.

PS C:\dev\repo> cd .\remote-repo\
PS C:\dev\repo\remote-repo> git branch
* dev
PS C:\dev\repo\remote-repo> git stash
No local changes to save
PS C:\dev\repo\remote-repo> git stash list
PS C:\dev\repo\remote-repo>
```

I really need that stash as it contains my uncommitted files. Are there any other alternatives to export my whole local repository (including unstaged changes)? I've tried copying the whole folder to another machine (another OS to be exact) but when I run git status, more files are shown under "unstaged changes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the bundle, add the ref `refs/stash`.

```
git bundle create ..\migrate.git  refs/stash dev <other_refs>
```

In my test, `--all` does not work. So I have to list all the refs I need, including `refs/stash`.

After you make a clone from the bundle and check out a branch(`dev` in your case), you can run `git fetch ../migrate.git refs/stash;git stash apply FETCH_HEAD` to retrieve the stashed changes. And then you can run `git stash` to recreate the stash if you'd like to apply it later.

If you have more than one stash entry, for example `stash@{0}` and `stash@{1}` by `git stash list`, you can make a tag for each stash entry. And add all of them to the bundle. Apply them in the new clone, and recreate the stash entries.

```
git tag stash0 stash@{0}
git tag stash1 stash@{1}
git bundle create ../migrate.git stash0 stash1 dev <other_refs>
cd ..
git clone migrate.git -- sample
cd sample
git checkout dev
git stash apply stash0
git stash
git stash apply stash1
git stash
git tag -d stash0 stash1
```